# Default page for MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As far as I know, which isn't a lot, there is no way to set a default page, like Default.aspx for an MVC 4 application, right?  I am developing MVC apps in convert with developers still working with Web Forms, which allows them create a default page.  In other words they have a Default.aspx page in their root folder and when the user enters http://www.example.com it will display that page.  We have a requirement to display some standard stuff before allowing the user to continue in any of the apps.  So would I create a Default.aspx or Default.cshtml file and use this as the initial display page then call another controller and action after the user agrees to the terms?  What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, you can set default route in RouteConfig.cs as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When the user first visits your page using www.example.com, the user will be redirected to `Home/Index` where you can place your terms and conditions. But, this might not be always the case as the user can navigate to any URL and you need a mechanism whether a user has accepted the terms and conditions or not. I would suggest putting a cookie or session variable saying the user has accepted the terms. Check whether the cookie or session exists or not. Otherwise redirect to your terms and conditions page. On terms and conditions page, don't check any cookies. You can check that cookie using a number of ways:

1) Using `ActionFilterAtribute` and overriding `OnActionExecuting`

2) Using `HttpModule`

3) Overriding `Application_BeginRequest()` inside `Global.asax.cs`

Comment: @Dean.DePue If I were you, I would not just show and hide the content based on some value. But, it is different for case to case. If you want users just to show the message on startup, your case might be okay. If you really want to enforce users to accept the terms and conditions, and only allowing them to view rest of contents and interact with the site, I would suggest a different approach.